# How to use other buildpacks with dokku-alt

Tags: heroku, docker, dokku, dokku-alt

I installed [dokku-alt](https://github.com/dokku-alt/dokku-alt) from the github repo, with the instructions provided, at a digital ocean droplet. I was able to run a node app and a python app, BUT I'm interested using [Shiny Buildpack](https://github.com/maxwellwood/heroku-buildpack-shiny) with dokku-alt to deploy Shiny Apps.

I already read the instructions a lot of times but I'm not understanding how to get this. I'm trying to install this example: https://github.com/btubbs/shiny-example-1

Comment: Finally a created another buildstep image with Shiny buidpack (https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/flaviobarros/dokku-alt-buildstep/). I can "git push" the shiny app, that is recognized as a Shiny app, BUT THE DOCKER CONTAINER DOESN'T START.

Comment: Note: I wouldn't use dokku-alt anymore, it's both not maintained and all of the below links point to dokku docs, not dokku-alt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I tryed hard to solve this problem and I've found the best solution. I could state the problem as: How can I git push a Shiny App on dokku/dokku-alt, the same way that it's possible to do with Django/Node apps?

The solution was the following feature: [Dockerfile deployment](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku~v0.5.0/deployment/dockerfiles/).

So, I created a small example, available on github: [Dockerized Shiny App](https://github.com/flaviobarros/shiny-wordcloud). It's available at Docker Hub too: [Dockerized Shiny App](https://hub.docker.com/r/flaviobarros/shiny-wordcloud/).

I wrote an article on r-bloggers stating the problem, the solution and I recorded a video with more instructions and examples: [Dockerizing a Shiny App](http://www.r-bloggers.com/dockerizing-a-shiny-app/).

Answer (score 1):

The dokku [docs](http://progrium.viewdocs.io/dokku/application-deployment) have instructions on how to specify a custom buildpack:

> If buildpack detection isn't working well for you or you want to
>   specify a custom buildpack for one repository you can create & commit
>   a file in the root of your git repository named .env containing export
>   BUILDPACK_URL= before pushing. This will tell buildstep to
>   fetch the specified buildpack and use it instead of relying on the
>   built-in buildpacks & their detection methods.

For example, one can put

```
export BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
```

in `.env`